# How to build a form to get data for a complex model in angular, for the purpose of then writing that data to firestore?

Tags: angular, forms, google-cloud-firestore, crud, angular-reactive-forms

## Preamble

So I'm building a system to manage some HR stuff, and I'm using Cloud Firestore as my backend. In terms of the data I'm handling, I'm using models to define what I need (sample model down below), then making forms based on these models to collect the data from the user. I then push said data to firebase. For most of my models the data is pretty simple and so I can do it with ease.
For example, I have *leave.model.ts*:

```ts
export class Leave {
    employeeID: string;
    organizationID: string;
    annualLeaveDays: number;
    maternityLeaveDays: number;
    paternityLeaveDays: number;
    sickLeaveDays: number;
    unpaidLeaveDays: number;
}
```

Which I then use to create a service for CRUD, *leave.service.ts*:

```ts
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Leave } from '../models/leave.model';

export class LeaveService {

  constructor(
    private firestore: AngularFirestore,
  ) {}

  createLeave(leave: Leave) {
    return this.firestore.collection('orgData').doc(leave.organizationID).collection('leaveDetails').doc(leave.employeeID).set(leave);
  }
}
```

I then use this service in my component when I build the form to collect and push the data to firebase:
*leave.component.ts*

```ts
import { LeaveService } from '../services/leave.service';
import { Leave } from '../models/leave.model';

import { FormArray, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

export class ManageLeaveComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    public leaveService: LeaveService,) {
  }

  newLeave: FormGroup;

  modalActive: boolean = false;

  Leaves: Leave[];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.newLeave = new FormGroup(
      {
        'employeeID': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        'organizationID': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        'annualLeaveDays': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        'maternityLeaveDays': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        'paternityLeaveDays': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        'sickLeaveDays': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        'unpaidLeaveDays': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      }
    );
  }

  newLeaveClick(){
    this.modalActive = true;
  }

  addLeave() {
    this.leaveService.createLeave(this.newLeave.value);
    this.modalActive = false;
  }
}
```

*leave.component.html*

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="buttonContainer">
        <button class="button is-primary" (click) = "newLeaveClick()">Add Leave Details</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal" [class.is-active] = "modalActive">
    <div class="modal-background" (click) = "modalClose()"></div>
    <div class="modal-content">
        <!-- Form for collecting new leave information -->
        <div class="box">
            <form [formGroup]="newLeave" (ngSubmit)="addLeave()">

                <div class="field">
                    <select
                    id = "tableSelect"
                    formControlName="organizationID"
                    (change)="getEmployees()"
                    [(ngModel)]="selectedOrganization">
                        <option
                        *ngFor = "let organization of Orgs"
                        [value] = "organization.organizationID" >{{ organization.organizationName }}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="field">
                    <select
                    id = "tableSelect"
                    formControlName="employeeID"
                    [(ngModel)]="selectedEmployee">
                        <option
                        *ngFor = "let employee of Employees"
                        [value] = "employee.id" >{{ employee.name }}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="field">
                    <label class="label">Annual Leave Days</label>
                    <input formControlName="annualLeaveDays" type="text" class="input">
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label class="label">Maternity Leave Days</label>
                    <input formControlName="maternityLeaveDays" type="text" class="input">
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label class="label">Paternity Leave Days</label>
                    <input formControlName="paternityLeaveDays" type="text" class="input">
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label class="label">Sick Leave Days</label>
                    <input formControlName="sickLeaveDays" type="text" class="input">
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label class="label">Unpaid Leave Days</label>
                    <input formControlName="unpaidLeaveDays" type="text" class="input">
                </div>
                

                <div class="buttonContainer">
                    <button class="button is-primary" type="submit">Add Leave Details</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*there are some extra functions but I left those out for brevity's sake*

## The Issue

What I'm having trouble with is creating a reactive form based on a model that isn't so simple:
*contract.model.ts*

```ts
export class Contract {
    contractID: string;
    // other basic details

    //this bit below is the complicated part. I need it to have an array that holds any number of benefits, depending on the contract details. The model is fine, but building a form to interact with it is what I don't get
    benefitsAllowances: {
        [benefitName: string]: {
            pay: string,
        }
    };
}
```

As I have it set up now, the service works the same as the one shown earlier. It expects an object of type Contract that it will then use to do the writing to firebase.
However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to use formGroup and formArray to collect the data for this, including the ability to have the user add as many benefits to the contract as necessary.
I assume on the HTML side I'd use the *ngFor* directive to display the benefits dynamically as they were added, but I don't get how to do that adding itself

If you need any more specificity just let me know.
Thanks in advance!

Edit 1:
Included more detail

Comment: So it sounds like you want your HTML template to display a form where you fill in these fields, a button to add another instance of a contract (to add to the FormArray), and then a submit button that takes all of this form data and uploads it to a Firestore document. Is that right? Are you able to provide some more specific details?

Comment: I am. lemme add more detail to the post

Comment: Using `benefitName: string` as your form control name means you will have to manually remove and create a new form control each time that name is changed, which makes the code more complex. Are you ok with the benefit name being a field instead of the key for simplicity?

Comment: Sure am! I'm open to considering new approaches. New to using models like this so I'm sure there's things I've done that aren't efficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to go about this problem, so here is one example with a modified model for reduced code complexity.

I modified your model to be like this:

```ts
export interface Contract {
  contractID: string;
  // other basic details

  benefitsAllowances: Benefit[]; // modified to hold an array of benefits
}

export interface Benefit {
  name: string;
  pay: string;
}
```

Instead of using the benefit name as the key, I added it as a field and created an array of benefits for `benefitsAllowances`. This allows us to reduce code complexity as we update the benefits (using the key as the form group name would require us to remove and create a new formgroup each time the name is changed).

Your new component will look like this:

```ts
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormArray, FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormGroupDirective, NgForm, Validators} from "@angular/forms";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-array',
  templateUrl: './form-array.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-array.component.scss']
})
export class FormArrayComponent implements OnInit {

  // form variables
  form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});
  benefitsAllowances: FormArray = new FormArray([]);

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      contractID: ['default id'],
      benefitsAllowances: this.formBuilder.array([])
    });
  }


  addItem(name: string, pay: string) {
    this.benefitsAllowances = this.form.get('benefitsAllowances') as FormArray;
    this.benefitsAllowances.push(
      this.formBuilder.group(
        {
          name: name,
          pay: pay
        } as Benefit
      ));
  }

  submit(form: FormGroup) {
    console.log(form.getRawValue());
  }
}
```

What I've done is I declared a variable `benefitsAllowances` which is of type `FormArray`. Each time we want to add a new benefit, the `addItem()` function is called which will add another benefit to the array.

The HTML template for this is as follows:

```html
<h3>Add new Benefit</h3>
<form (ngSubmit)="addItem(name.value, pay.value); name.value = ''; pay.value = '';">
  <label for="benefit">Benefit Name:</label>
  <input #name id="benefit" type="text">

  <label for="benefit-pay">Benefit Pay:</label>
  <input #pay id="benefit-pay" type="number">
  <button>Add Item</button>
</form>


<h3>Current Benefits</h3>
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit(form)">
  <div
    formArrayName="benefitsAllowances"
    *ngFor="let benefit of benefitsAllowances.controls; let i = index;">

    <div [formGroupName]="i">
      <label for="benefit-{{ i }}">Benefit Name:</label>
      <input id="benefit-{{ i }}" type="text" formControlName="name">

      <label for="benefit-pay-{{ i }}">Benefit Pay:</label>
      <input id="benefit-pay-{{ i }}" type="text" formControlName="pay">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

{{form.getRawValue() | json}}
```

When you fill out the form and add a new benefit, it gets added to your form group and displayed via the `ngFor` loop, where you can then add another benefit or edit an existing one thanks to two-way data binding.

On submit you will be able to upload these benefits as an array to Firestore.

Here's a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wkf9nh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for a live demo

Comment: This actually makes so much sense! Thanks for this!
I've definitely learned a lot from just this example.

Apparently I don't have enough rep to upvote, so have this thumbs up ^

Thanks again Ser Hydra!